# replacing escape character sequences in objective c

Tags: objective-c, string

I have a query that returns a string, as well as an escape character sequence. (ex. "USA\"")

I am using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` in this fashion:

```
[theCountry stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
```

But it is still leaving behind a set of quotes. and if I were to try the method again to remove them:

```
[theCountry stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@""" withString:@""];
```

I would have an incomplete set of quotes...
I need to get rid of both the slash and the double quotes.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Actually, could you clarify: Does your string include the leading and trailing quotes and you want to get USA\" from "USA\""?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash:

```
NSString* foo = @"USA\\\"";
NSLog(@"String [%@]", foo);
foo = [foo stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\"" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"String [%@]", foo);
```

Results in

```
2009-11-02 09:15:24.403 test[6098:903] String [USA\"]
2009-11-02 09:15:24.406 test[6098:903] String [USA]
```